# Call a function when directive value change ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with a CMS (Jahia), that give me a variable called loggedIn that change to either true or false when I'm connected or not.

I take this variable from a JSP.

```
function navBarLinks(CONTEXT) {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: {
                currentLanguage: '@',
                userPreferredLanguage: '@',
                isLogged: '='
                // lang à supprimer dans la .jsp
            },
            controller: NavBarLinksController,
            controllerAs: 'navbarlinksCtrl',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
```

This variable works well, but I got an "Activate" function that is called each time I load my page. I would like to watch my isLogged each time the function activate is called (This function is in the controller). And when this value changes, and ONLY when it changes, call a function.

Tried $scope.$watch.

Comment: Add a `link` function and put `$scope.$watch` your variable inside the function

Comment: Into the directive ?